# how to get clickable DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I would like to open the first collapsible card component when the page loads.
As step 2, I would like to open other cards as well, but first, I would like to figure this one out. I got stuck with how to select the clickable DOM element.

The html structure:

```
<app-card>
  <div class="card">
    <div role="tab" class="card-header" id="ngb-panel-0-header">
      <div class="d-flex d-row justify-content-between">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-start">
          <p>Card Title</p>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
          <div class="w-25 collapsed">
            <button type="button" ng-reflect-ngb-panel-toggle class="btn btn-link collapsed</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</app-card>
```

In the .ts file, I have tried to select the button, but with querySelector the selected element is not clickable:

```
ngOnInit() {
  document.querySelector('#ngb-panel-0-header > div > div.d-flex.justify-content-end > div > button').click();
  }
```

Can someone please help me how to select this DOM element and click on it?

Comment: You've got broken syntax on the button for starters, but are all you trying to do is find that specific element, or like find the first in the DOM, or could you be more specific? An easy way with angular is just use [viewChild](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-viewchild/) or if you want js just give it a unique ID and do `document.getElementById('your-id')` or if you want to traverse a DOM flow you could `querySelectorAll` for buttons and go from there...but I'm not entirely sure what you're after.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "not clickable"? Is there an error in your console? You don't seem to specify a click event, so what do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use template reference by adding hash and then template reference name.

Ex:

```
<button #targetButton type="button" ng-reflect-ngb-panel-toggle class="btn btn-link collapsed</button>
```

Then in the `ts` file, you need to declare the template ref.

```
@ViewChild('targetButton') targetButton: ElementRef;
```

And in the `ngOnInit` lifecycle, you can `click` the button

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.targetButton.nativeElement.click();
}
```